# Cargar activity con un dato de la base de datos de Firebase

Tags: firebase

estoy haciendo el proyecto de final de curso de DAM y en la app que estoy creando me gustaria saber como puedo cargar una actividad a traves de un codigo que existe en la base de datos. Estoy trabajando con Firebase y este es el metodo que estoy usando.

```
   public void joinEvent(View view) {

    codigo=Codigo.getText().toString();

    DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference events = root.child("Events");
    events.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.child(codigo).exists()) {
                // run some code
            }else {

                Toast.makeText( context, "Código Invalido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EventActivity.class);
   // intent.putExtra("code",mCode.getText().toString());
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Una de las formas mas sencillas es mediante el uso de `SharedPreferences`, en el cual guardas tus datos de manera local, parecido a una base de datos pero mas simple y para datos no tan extensos. Funciona incluso cuando la `Activity` es destruida o puesta en pausa.

Comment: todavia necesitas ayuda en esta pregunta?

Comment: No, esto ya lo tengo superado pero gracias por preguntar, en cuanto saque un poco de tiempo le meto mano a la respuesta que me distes el otro día a otra pregunta y te comentaré. Muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Una forma seria mediante el uso de `SharedPreferences`, en cual puedes guardar información de manera local como si crearas una base de datos SQL pero de una forma mas sencilla.

**Ejemplo**

Supongamos que en `MiActivity` necesitas tomar la información que se recibe desde `FireBase`, para guardar dichos datos haces lo siguiente:

**Mi Activity:**

```
public void joinEvent(View view) {

codigo=Codigo.getText().toString();

DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference events = root.child("Events");
events.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.child(codigo).exists()) {
            Context context = getActivity();
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Mis_preferences",context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("code", mCode);
            editor.apply();
        }else {

            Toast.makeText( context, "Código Invalido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});

Intent intent = new Intent(this, EventActivity.class);
// intent.putExtra("code",mCode.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);

}
```

Luego, en `OtraActivity` puedes recuperar esa información de la siguiente manera:

**Otra Activity:**

```
Context context = getActivity();
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Mis_preferences",context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String mCode = sharedPreferences.getString("code","No hay dato");//"No hay dato" es el valor por defecto que mostrara si no se encuentra el dato guardado
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta y por el aporte pero la app es para hacer quedadas, un usuario crea un evento para x dia con varios datos, entre ellos un codigo aleatoria el cual pasa a los amigos y estos son los que tienen que meter el codigo e ir a la activity que el primer usuario a creado con todos los datos